# What do I do when Spartan Ops. lags?

Tags: halo-4

I started playing Spartan Ops. on legendary with a few friends because I already played all the episodes myself on normal. But when we were playing it, the screen freezes at random moments. When I pressed the fire button, it didn't shoot, etc. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Check your console to see if its overheating.

Comment: Storage space, lowering your display and clearing your cache may fix this. Also, if a low quality USB storage is plugged in this too could possibly cause console lagging. Vaccuum your power pack.